# How do you format current system datetime as UTC using String.format in Java?

Tags: java, datetime-format, utc, java-time, localdate

This code

```
String.format("%1$tY%1$tm%1$td", new Date());
```

gives a YYYYmmdd format using the current system time but the time zone is the current system default as well. How to make this code gives UTC date?

I tried

```
String.format("%1$tY%1$tm%1$td", Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant()));
```

but not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ZonedDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now().withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println(String.format("%1$tY%1$tm%1$td", zonedDateTime));
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought String.format has to take a Date object.

Comment: @user1589188 - I suggest you use `DateTimeFormatter` which is not only specialized for formatting date, time, and time-zone information but also many other features like defaulting the parts of date-time to some values, localizing etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to display just year, month and day, the most appropriate class for this would be [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Also, I suggest you use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) which is not only specialized for formatting date, time, and time-zone information but also many other features like defaulting the parts of date-time to some values, localizing etc.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Today at UTC
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        // Define the formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd");

        // Display LocalDate in its default format
        System.out.println(date);

        // Display LocalDate in the custom format
        System.out.println(date.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-11
20200911
```

Note that `java.util.Date` does not represent a Date/Time object. It simply represents the no. of milliseconds from the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. It does not have any time-zone or zone-offset information. When you print it, Java prints the string obtained by combining the date and time based on the time-zone of your JVM with the time-zone of your JVM. Date and time API from `java.util` is mostly deprecated and error-prone. I suggest you stop using `java.util.Date` and switch to `java.time` API.

The `java.time` API has a rich set of classes for different purposes e.g. if you need the information about the date and time, you can use `LocalDateTime` and if you need the information about the date, time, and time-zone, you can use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`. The following table shows an [overview of date-time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) available in `java.time` package:

[image]

Learn more about [the modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.